# MySQL query that lists all instances of duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have a table of people that has many duplicate records (first name and last name are the same). I am trying to write a query that will list all the intances of those records. I dont want to group them because I need to see the duplicate records with the member ID number. For example, if I have 3 Joe Smiths in the table, I want to see this listing after running the query:

```
MemberID   FirstName    LastName
8746       Joe          Smith
8944       Joe          Smith
9774       Joe          Smith
```

I made an attempt to write a query, but it just lists all the records in the table. Here is what I tried that did not do what I want:

```
 SELECT membership.Member_ID,membership.FirstName,membership.LastName    
 FROM membership WHERE membership.FirstName = membership.FirstName AND
 membership.LastName = membership.LastName;
```

Comment: If any of the answers below has solved/helped you to solve your problem, Kindly accept the answer and/or upvote the answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can self join here as follows:

```
SELECT distinct 
 m1.Member_ID,m1.FirstName,m1.LastName    
 FROM membership m1
 inner join membership m2
 on m1.memberid = m2.memberid
 where m1.FirstName = m2.FirstName 
 AND m1.LastName = m2.LastName
 and m1.id <> m2.id;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is in fact the way to go, in my opinion. [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) has a very useful [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function for these situations exactly:

```
SELECT   FirstName, LastName, GROUP_CONCAT(MemberID) AS ids
FROM     membership
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Member_ID, FirstName, LastName    
FROM membership
WHERE CONCAT(FirstName, LastName) IN ( SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, LastName)
                                       FROM membership
                                       GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
                                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all duplicate records you can use a correlated sub query also

```
select a.* 
from demo a
where (
  select count(*)
  from demo b
  where a.FirstName = b.FirstName
  and a.LastName = b.LastName
) > 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/593345/5)